# "No instance of overloaded function CreateWidget" error when trying to add viewport through C++ in Unreal

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

I'm trying to add a user widget to my viewport through C++ in Unreal.
I want to make the user widget a public UPROPERTY so that I can add the blueprint of the widget on the blueprint of the player class.

The arguments look to be matching the definition so I cannot understand why I keep getting the error:
"No instance of overloaded function CreateWidget matches the argument list"

What am I doing wrong here?

In my player class I have:

// player.h

```
UPROPERTY(EditDefaultsOnly, BlueprintReadOnly, Category = "Player, HUD and UI")
    TSubclassOf<class UUserWidget*> CrossHairsClass;


    UPROPERTY(EditDefaultsOnly, BlueprintReadOnly, Category = "Player, HUD and UI")
    class UUserWidget*  CrossHairs;
```

And in the BeginPlay() function of my player cpp class I have

// player.cpp

```
if (CrossHairsClass) {
        CrossHairs = CreateWidget<UUserWidget>(this, CrossHairsClass);
        CrossHairs->AddToViewport();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Refering to UE4 [CreateWidget documentation](https://api.unrealengine.com/INT/API/Runtime/UMG/Blueprint/CreateWidget/index.html), you have to add the `WidgetName`parameter in the `CreateWidget` function, for example:

```
CrossHairs = CreateWidget<UUserWidget>(this, CrossHairsClass, FName(TEXT("CrossHairWidget")));
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: If this solves, remember to mark as solved and put an upvote, thanks